# How do I debug c++ in vscode

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I use the vscode config like below:

`launch.json`

```js
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/ss-client",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true,
                    "directory": "/src"
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

`c_cpp_properties.json`

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}",
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

The project use Makefile to build and generated binary(ss-client) is in the same folder with project source files(/src) . How should I include source files that are not in the same folder with binary to make debugger(gdb) aware of those files?

Comment: What problem are you having? How are you compiling the code?

Comment: `c_cpp_properties.json` is irrelevant for debugging